# How to apply a lot of boolean object, but doesnt make subdivide the main object into weird things?

Tags: modifiers

How to apply a lot of boolean object, but doesnt make subdivide the main object into weird things?

I has some problem with boolean modifier where i want colouring the holes on my object differenly with the surface of my padle racket. surely it doesnt make any mess before i used subdivide, but when i used it my object turns so weird like the image that i attached below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: your boolean gives a bad topology, you have at least 3 solutions: dont give your object a Subdivision Surface modifier (probably not what you want) / correct the topology (a bit tedious) / don't use a boolean to create your holes, use another method (like bevel vertices)

Comment: or maybe i can change the vertices into circle and made a holes from those method, than bevel it. but, is it possible to doing that?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, maybe show your topology or even share your file?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/14R1kgSPHrJokzMfVFEhl2t3f7HyqF-Cm/view?usp=sharing   This is my blender file. maybe you was right the problems is my topology. but i dont know what is the method to topology between the lot of holes like this.

Comment: your link asks for an authorization, but as I said, if you want to give your object a Subdivision Surface modifier you need a clean topology, an easy way to create holes is to create a grid, then select the vertices and bevel them, see this tutorial (you can create holes with only 6 or 8 vertices): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ho7MfAV3mGs

Comment: Thanks a lot moonbots, you has solved my problem